# Is there a way to append multiple elements to an existing string using a FOR loop?

Tags: r, loops, syntax, append, sqldf

I am working on creating a data frame column summaries for multiple columns in R using SQL (sqldf). The reason I went with this method instead of doing it directly in SQL is because there was some additional plotting I had to do and my manager wanted me to keep all code in one file.
This is the basic example of how the syntax for sqldf looks like:

```
Result1 <- sqldf("
        SELECT ColumnName,
        COUNT(ColumnName) as Total,
        FROM AnalysisFile
        GROUP BY ColumnName")
```

Overall, the way I completed the task is: 1) import the file, 2) run 6-7 separate queries for the columns of interest, 3) write all of them as a single .xlsx file using this code:

```
column_names <- list('Result1' = Result1, 'Result2' = Result2)
path_out = "C:\Users\Desktop"
write.xlsx(column_names, file = paste(path_out, 'SummaryResults', Sys.Date(), '.xlsx'))
```

Everything works fine, but **here is the challenge**: my manager wants me to create a FOR loop that only uses a vector with column names as an input, so that we won't have to change the query/output code every time we want to run this process for different columns or documents.

This means, I have to create a loop that will iterate through column names, appending them to different places in the sqldf string, creating multiple data frames, then concatenating them together into a single .xlsx file for sharing with other departments.

This is an example of what I attempted (I'm more used to Python and only have 1 year of coding experience in general, so forgive me for terrible syntax):

```
ColumnNames <- c('Column1','Column2')

for (i in ColumnNames) { 
 ( "
        SELECT " + i + "
        COUNT(" + i + ") as Total,
        ROUND(count(" + i + ") * 100.0/SUM(COUNT("+ i +")) over(), 2) as Total_Percentage
        from AnalysisFile
        group by " + i+"
)
}
```

This obviously gives me multiple errors and I am not sure how to approach this issue, let alone also automate the output by iterating through column names in the next chunk of code. If there is a better way to achieve the result, this will work as well.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For that first part you might want to use glue / glue_sql - https://glue.tidyverse.org/reference/glue_sql.html . In most case you don't have to loop or iterate over  vectors, there's a good chance that you can just pass a vector instead of a single value and you'll get a vector back,  i.e. `glue( "SELECT {col}, COUNT({col}) as Total, ... ", col = c("aaa", "bbb"))` returns `"SELECT aaa, COUNT(aaa) as Total, ... "` and  `"SELECT bbb, COUNT(bbb) as Total, ... "`

Comment: You can do things like this: `for(i in column_names) print(fn$sqldf("select $i from myData"))` if the column names have only word characters (letters, numbers and underscore) in them.  If not surround them with backticks: ``for(i in column_names) print(fn$sqldf("select `i` from myData"))``  The `fn$` enables the substitution.  Use the `verbose=TRUE` argument to `sqldf` if you want it to print out the final SQL statement that it is using.

Comment: Also please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and, in particular, questions to SO should be complete including all inputs (shown using `dput`) and all `library` statements so that others can copy and paste the code from the question to their R session and run it.